# From stereo to mono

Tags: stereo, mono

There is an audio splitter from 1 stereo to 2 mono.

The stereo plug is connected to the common audio exit of the pc.
If I connect the stereo jack of audio headset with the mono1, why do I listen the sound only from just one speaker?

I suppose to listen the audio from left speaker with mono1 and with the right speaker with mono2.

Answer (score 1):

You *will* hear the left audio from mono 1 and the right audio from mono 2, but if you are plugging a stereo headset into either one of them, you will always hear the audio through the same side of the headset. I can’t remember exactly, but I think that will always be the left side. That is because a mono plug is essentially the left side of a stereo plug. Mono has only one side.

If you want to hear mono 1 through the left side and mono 2 through the right side, that is actually stereo. You don’t want to use the mono adapter in that case. What you want to do is use a balance/pan control set all the way left to hear the left side of the audio in your left ear and silence in the right, and then set the balance/pan all the way right to hear the right side of the audio in your right ear and silence in the left.

Answer (score 0):

You need an adapter that takes the single signal on your mono output and connect it to both side of a stereo headphones.

If all your connectors are 3.5 jacks, here's an example of such a product : [http://www.amazon.com/Monoprice-107158-Stereo-Adaptor-Plated/dp/B003DBTAZ4](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003DBTAZ4)